# Can't see Database Objects -> SQL Server Projects in Visual Studio when attempting to create CLR function

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I need to create a CLR function (in C#) to support business needs. I've already got the code ready. All that's needed is to create a server project in visual studio, add the code in and compile it. This is where I am having trouble. As stated in the title, I am unable to see the Database Objects option when I go to create a new project. All I am seeing are BI Projects and Other Project types -> VS Solutions.

Here is what I have installed on *my* workstation:

- SQL Server 2005 Workstations components (can't install the full
  server - licensing restriction).
- SQL Server 2012 Express

Microsoft really don't make things easy for developers. Does anyone know how I can get the SQL Server Projects option to show up in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have figured it out. I needed to install the full version of Visual Studio in order to have this option.